# Find specific values and then return corresponding value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am beginning to write a formula in B9. This formula will be applied to all similar rows down the sheet.

What I am wanting to do is for B9 to check for al instances of "In-progress" in its respective row. Then if it does find an occurence, find the column header and return that value.

For example:

In row 9, I would want B9 to find cells AF9 and AG9. Then in the return for B9, it would be "Marketing Plan, Website Launched".

I'm not sure where to start with this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I saw an example online with a formula like this. I tried it out with no luck. It returns #value.

```
=INDEX($T$8:$AV$8,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($T$8:$AV$8="In-progress")*(COLUMN($T$8:$AV$8))))-(COLUMN($T$8)+1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REPT($AF$8:$AG$8,AF9:AG9="In-Progress"))
```

---

Or just use `IF()` with `TEXTJOIN()`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(AF9:AG9="In-Progress",$AF$8:$AG$8,""))
```

---

In context of the OP it will be :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(T9:AV9="In-Progress",$T$8:$AV$8,""))
```

---

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no version constraints as per your tags, you can use the following:

```
B9: =TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER($T$8:$AV$8,$T9:$AV9="in-progress"))
```